# precedence diagram method with graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want to draw a precedence diagram with graphviz

This is my code in question, that should show a node in the precedence diagram:

```
digraph D {
    node [shape=record]
    8 [ label = <
    <table border="1" bgcolor="white" color="black">
       <tr>
         <td colspan="1">Nr</td>
         <td colspan="2">Name</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="1">D</td>
         <td colspan="1">GP</td>
         <td colspan="1">FP</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  > ]
}
```

it should look like seen on this website: https://t2informatik.de/wissen-kompakt/netzplan/

This is only for more context to get the idea what I want to archive:

```
digraph D {
    node [shape=record]
    1 [label="{1 | Planung} | {1 | 0 | 0 }"];
    2 [label="{1 | Vorbereitung} | {1 | 0 | 0 }"];
    3 [label="{1 | Geräte kaufen} | {1 | 0 | 0 }"];
    4 [label="{1 | Geräte bestellen} | {1 | 0 | 0 }"];
    5 [label="{1 | Geräte aufbauen} | {1 | 0 | 0 }"];
    6 [label="{1 | Geräte prüfen} | {1 | 0 | 0 }"];
    7 [label="{1 | Abnahme durch Kunden} | {1 | 0 | 0 }"];
    8 [ label = <
    <table border="1" bgcolor="white" color="black">
       <tr>
         <td colspan="1">Nr</td>
         <td colspan="2">Name</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="1">D</td>
         <td colspan="1">GP</td>
         <td colspan="1">FP</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  > ]
    rankdir=LR;
1 -> 2;
2 -> {3,4};
3 -> 6;
4 -> {5,7};
5 -> 6;
6 -> 7;
}
```

Any help is welcome. Maybe HTML-like tables are not the way to go. If there are better approaches feel free to tell me. (I wonder that precedence diagrams don't work out of the box or i did miss that option)

Comment: please explicit state what is "wrong" with your current graph.

Answer (score 0):

I just asked chat-gpt, the answer is here:

```
digraph G {
  node [shape=plaintext, fontsize=12];

  table [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Nr</td><td colspan="2">Name des Prozesses</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>>, height=2, width=2.5];

}
```

Comment: Please read Stack Overflow's policies on chatGPT content. https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy